# How to predict a new data series with a trained Keras GRU model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to use a trained Keras sequence model (GRU) to predict some new data samples, but have some problem creating the time series generator.

In the training process, the validation set was predicted using `model.predict_generator()`, which used a Python generator created by `keras.preprocessing.sequence.TimeseriesGenerator()` ([link](https://keras.io/preprocessing/sequence/)) as input. I wanted to repeat the process with a new test set, only to find that `TimeseriesGenerator()` needs both data and targets as input. But in this case, I expect to get the targets (i.e. `y_test`) with the predict function.

A simplified version of my training code looks like this:

```
training_generator = TimeseriesGenerator(X_train, y_train, length=timesteps * sampling_rate, sampling_rate=sampling_rate, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=shuffle_data)
test_generator = TimeseriesGenerator(X_test, y_test, length=timesteps * sampling_rate, sampling_rate=sampling_rate, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=shuffle_data)

model.fit_generator(generator=training_generator, epochs=epochs, use_multiprocessing=False, verbose=2)
y_test_pred = model.predict_generator(generator=test_generator)
```

I also thought about writing a custom generator by myself, but then it would be really hard to validate the equivalence between this generator and the official time series generator.

Is there any way to use `TimeseriesGenerator()` without giving `targets`?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple workaround would be to generate dummy targets, since `predict_generator` will ignore them:

```
X_test =  your new test data
y_dummy = np.zeros((X_test.shape[0], ))
test_generator = TimeseriesGenerator(X_test, y_dummy, length=timesteps * sampling_rate, sampling_rate=sampling_rate, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=shuffle_data)
y_test_pred = model.predict_generator(generator=test_generator)
```

You should adjust the shape of `y_dummy` if your labels are multidimensional.

Comment: Thanks Matias! That's exactly what I just tried, and it worked. I'm just wondering if this influences the prediction result in any way...

Comment: @Jianyu No, the y labels are ignored by predict_generator

Comment: Got it. I'll repeat the dummy target process with some training samples and compare. Thanks!